# How to get an access_token for Element / Riot / Matrix?

Tags: riot.im

In the [Matrix](https://matrix.org/) instant messaging protocol, when using the reference implementation of the Matrix server (called `synapse`), there is an [admin API](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/blob/master/docs/admin_api/) with functions like [resetting a password](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/blob/master/docs/admin_api/user_admin_api.rst#reset-password) for a user etc..

Accessing this requires an [`access_token`](https://matrix.org/docs/spec/client_server/latest#using-access-tokens) "API key" of a server admin user.

How do I get one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solution to find your access token:

1. Log in to the account you want to get the access token for. Click on the name in the top left corner, then "Settings".
2. Click the "Help & About" tab (left side of the dialog).
3. Scroll to the bottom and click on `<click to reveal>` part of Access
   Token.
4. Copy your access token to a safe place.

Comment: In Element, `Help & About` was all the way at the bottom of settings. And then Access Token was at the bottom of the `Help & About` pane, under the `Advanced` heading.

Answer (score 5):

These `access_token` API keys were listed in the [Riot](https://riot.im/) web application until not too long ago, somewhere under the account settings. In the newest version, I could no longer find them there.

So instead, I use a technique I found [here](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/issues/1707#issuecomment-405455882), which is basically a login procedure done with `curl`. The server's answer will contain the `access_token`.

1. Find out the Matrix user ID and password of a server admin user. The username has to be in the fully qualified form, for example `@user:example.com`.
2. Execute the following command on a Linux-based system that has `curl` installed. Of course, supply the address of you Matrix server for `example.com`, and also your Matrix user ID and password.

   ```
   curl -XPOST \
     -d '{"type":"m.login.password", "user":"<userid>", "password":"<password>"}' \
     "https://example.com:8448/_matrix/client/r0/login"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of the Matrix protocol, getting an access_token programmatically works slightly different:

To find out the endpoint, e.g., for matrix.org, you need to check a `.well-known` file for the API URL ([Documentation](https://spec.matrix.org/v1.1/client-server-api/#well-known-uri)): `https://matrix.org/.well-known/matrix/client`:

```
$ curl https://matrix.org/.well-known/matrix/client
{
    "m.homeserver": {
        "base_url": "https://matrix-client.matrix.org"
    },
    "m.identity_server": {
        "base_url": "https://vector.im"
    }
}
```

Afterwards, the homeserver base url can be used for the curl call ([See Documentation for the /login endpoint](https://spec.matrix.org/v1.1/client-server-api/#post_matrixclientv3login)):

```
$ curl '{"type":"m.login.password", "user":"'$username'", "password":"'$password'"} \ 
"https://$base_url/_matrix/client/v3/login"

{
  "user_id":"@username:matrix.org",
  "access_token":"token",
  "home_server":"matrix.org",
  "device_id":"ID",
  "well_known": { 
    "m.homeserver": {
      "base_url":"https://matrix-client.matrix.org/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course this method only works if the Matrix home server allows the `m.login.password` Authentication type... matrix.org does, but e.g. gitter.im does not. In that case, you get `{"errcode":"M_UNKNOWN","error":"Password login has been disabled."}`